# How to change the background color of the selected cell after pushing?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an application in which I am changing the color of the selected cell by using the  `cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_gray_with_line.png"]];`. But when I am doing this after selecting in the didselect it is not changing my background back to the previous view, after pushing

```
if (indexPath != nil) {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];    
}
```

I need the same background as normal when popping back to this view controller, without reloading the table view. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

You should set two properties to your `UITableViewCell`.

1. backgroundView
2. selectedBackgroundView

Also, you should set `cell.selectionStyle` to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`.

Comment: i am doing it bu backgroundcolor for some reasons.that is the problem here

Answer (score 1):

UITableViewControllers will, if their `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` property is set to YES, deselect the selected row on viewWillAppear.  If you're not using a table view controller with that setting (default is YES, I think), do it yourself:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Implement the did (or will) deselect delegate method and fix your color:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    // do what you want to the cell
}
```

Incidentally, others on SO recommend setting the color on the cell's content view (not `cell.backgroundColor`, but `cell.contentView.backgroundColor`), and doing so in `willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: i did it but not solved. i was not in a position to reload tableview.

Answer (score 0):

This should do,

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
 [super viewDidAppear:animated];
 [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] ].backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"normal.png"]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //First you get the cell you want to change
    UITableViewCell* theCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    //Then you change the properties (label, text, color etc..) in your case, the background color
    theCell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];

    //Deselect the cell so you can see the color change

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

same answer as @dand, but modify a little bit.

```
- (void) viewWillAppear: (BOOL) animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear: animated];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableview indexPathForSelectedRow];
    [self.tableview deselectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath animated: YES];
}
```

and modify this method in your custom cell implementation.

```
- (void) setSelected: (BOOL) selected animated: (BOOL) animated
{
    [super setSelected: selected animated: animated];
    // Configure the view for the selected state

    if (selected)
    {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    else
    {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
}
```